# triggering click on iframe did not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, iframe

check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GxPmU/

I tried to bind a click event on that iframe, however, clicking on the iframe does not trigger the click event accordingly

moreover the firebug console also outputs errors:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property 'nodeType'
[Break On This Error]   

if ( selector.nodeType ) {
```

Any idea what I did wrong and how to be able to bind the click event on the iframe accordingly?

Comment: Classical case of "[Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of the "[Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)" you can't get the click event.

I've created a demo to show this behavior. The first link is on the same origin and therefor the click is passed. The second one on the other hand does not response:

**HTML**

```
<iframe id="iframe-test-1" src="jsfiddle.net/404"></iframe>
<iframe id="iframe-test-2" src="http://jsfiddle.net/404"></iframe>
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/V9WTA/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just know whenever a click on any part of `iFrame` happens, just put the `iFrame` in a `div` and bind the event to the `div`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the z-index of the div to be before the iframe as well as make it absolute.

```
div#foo
{
    z-index: 9999;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/8S9S7/)

You may need to resize and relocate the div based on the iframe.

Comment: This will disable the interaction with the iframe.

Comment: That is true. This is only to emulate an onclick; which they cannot do cross origin as explained by your answer.