# Why $(document).on(event, sel, f); doesn't work but $(document).find(sel).on(event, f); does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, event-listener

I tried to set up an event listener with jquery in an iframe with the following code :

```
function reportThanks() {                                                                                                                           
    //$(document).find('a.report-button').on('click', function (event) {
    $(document).on('click', 'a.report-button', function (event) {
        alert("Thx!");
  });
}
```

With the current (uncommented) code, the `alert()` isn't triggered. But it is with the previous one (commented).

What is the difference between those that could explain that one works, and the other doesn't?

Is the problem related to the [same origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15253763/3156085) since it's in an iframe?

Note : The event listener is set up in the iframe.

Comment: Events don't bubble outside of their owner document, and jQuery's event delegation relies on bubbling. You'll need to set up a handler inside the `iframe`.

Comment: I tested with the following and both functions get triggered : `$(document).find('a.report-button').on('click', function(event) {
  console.log("Clicked! First Listener!");
});
$(document).on('click', 'a.report-button', function(event) {
  console.log("Clicked! Second Listener!");
});`

Comment: @CrazyTrain The event listener is set inside the iframe

Comment: Create a complete demo that represents the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Event delegation won't work if there's an element that contains `a.report-button` that also has a `click` handler, and that handler calls `event.stopPropagation()`. Delegation depends on the event bubbling to the element that you bind the handler to (`document` in your case). When the event reaches `document`, jQuery checks whether the original target matches `a.report-button` to determine whether the handler should run.
`stopPropagation()` stops bubbling, so the event never reaches `document`.

The solution is to bind your event to a closer container that's inside the element that stops the propagation.

```
$("#container").on("click", "a.report-button", function(event) {
    alert("Thx!");
});
```